# How to require login in opencart? (Private Shopping)

Tags: opencart

l want to private shopping with Open cart. How?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCart does not have a feature that enables you to set the shop up to require a username and password before accessing the shop.

You can configure it to require a log-in before check-out, and also to log-in before showing prices.  From the admin interface...

```
Login Display Prices: 
Only show prices when a customer is logged in.
yes/no

Guest Checkout:
Allow customers to checkout without creating an account. This will not be available when a downloadable product is in the shopping cart.
yes/no
```

However, although OpenCart doesn't provide the functionality you're looking for, it'd be easy to add with an OpenCart extension.  You could write one, or it looks like there is one in the OpenCart extensions directory already, see http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6230